# Ember.js - Delay update until ajax call complete

Tags: ember.js

What's the recommended pattern for not displaying an unloaded intermediate result while waiting for slow AJAX calls to complete?

E.g. I have some controller code like this:

```
this.set('content', function () { Model.find(/* return some long running operation */) });
```

And while the app is waiting for that function to return some data it sets the content of the page to an empty object.

Ideally, if there is already loaded content that would stay displaying until the new content is ready to be rendered. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Promises are a good pattern for this.

```
var _this = this;
App.ModelObject.find(...).then(function(results){
   _this.set('content', results)
}
```

You don't say if `ModelObject#find` is something you implemented yourself, or if you are using a library, so the promise may be something available for you out of the box or something you would implement yourself using Ember.RSVP.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this like so (this is inside my controller when loading a new object):

```
var _this = this;
search = App.ModelObject.find(...);
search.addObserver('property_that_exists_on_loaded_+object', function (search) {
    _this.set('content', search);
});
```

I'm not sure but this may be missing some code to remove the observer after it has loaded which is what most examples of using `addObserver` do.

I'm also not sure if this will fail to fire if that property is updated before the `addObserver` is registered to the object.